# how to use the edmx and functions created by it for calling stored procs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, edmx

I have the edmx in the DAL and it has automatically created functions and complex types for all the stored procs. I am able to call the stored procs using the entity object.

Now in the Business Logic Layer I am creating an object for DAL in a class level. 
i.e

```
public class ProjectBO   //Business object
    {
       ProjectEntities Entities = new ProjectEntities();


       public IEnumerable<usp_Project_Team_GetTeam_Result> usp_Project_Team_GetTeam(string strAssociateId)
       {
           return Entities.usp_Project_Team_GetTeam(strAssociateId);
       }
}
```

I call this function from handlers. So my question is since i have created the object for entity in class level, will the connection be opened as soon the object is created and it will remain open throughout??
are there any equivalent command like `connection.close()` to close the connection when it is not needed to open it?! or will the edmx open and close the connection as soon as the data is fetched from the db ???

Answer (score 1):

Your **Entities** variable is within the scope of an instance of **ProjectBO**. So when your garbage collector runs, your DB connection will be cleaned up. Not ideal.

A better option is to explicitly give it a narrower scope:

```
public IEnumerable<usp_Project_Team_GetTeam_Result> usp_Project_Team_GetTeam(string strAssociateId)
{
   using (ProjectEntities Entities = new ProjectEntities())
   {
       return Entities.usp_Project_Team_GetTeam(strAssociateId);
   }
}
```

This way your connection will be opened and closed exactly where you would expect.

Comment: Thanks LachlanB, if i have say 80+ functions is it still better to use this explicit way, considering that it would add up another 200loc, and one more clarification, since i am creating the object for Entity at class level will the DB connection kept open all along??

Comment: The DB connection will be closed as soon as the Entities class falls out of scope, right after the first } bracket.

Comment: Hi LachlanB,
I am getting "Object disposed" error
is it same if we use 

public IEnumerable<usp_Project_Team_GetTeam_Result> usp_Project_Team_GetTeam(string strAssociateId)
{
   ProjectEntities Entities = new ProjectEntities()
   
       return Entities.usp_Project_Team_GetTeam(strAssociateId);
   
}

Comment: Return a List and convert it to a list beforehand.